# useRef typescript 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've an issue using typescript with useRef:

```
 <div ref={(el) => (listRef.current[v.name] = el)}>{v.name}</div>
```

v.name is a string and it doesn't work for my interface:

```
interface listRefObj {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

I got error of `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{} | listRefObj'`

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-8fnog1?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `el` can be `HTMLDivElement | null` (and not `string`). So the correct annotation should be:

```
interface listRefObj {
  [key: string]: HTMLDivElement | null;
}
```

Also the ref type needs to be just `listRefObj` i.e. `useRef<listRefObj>({})`

## Complete code

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface listRefObj {
  [key: string]: HTMLDivElement | null;
}

export default function App() {
  const listRef = useRef<listRefObj>({});

  const result = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "apple"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "orange"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {result.map((v) => (
        <div ref={(el) => (listRef.current[v.name] = el)}>{v.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```